# HttpContextBase and System.Web in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I originally have code using `HttpContextBase` from `System.Web` in my `ASP.NET Web MVC` project.

I would like to extend this functionality to a project that is using `.NET Core` by moving the code into a `.NET Standard Library` so both projects using `ASP.NET Web MVC` and `ASP.NET Core` respectively can use it.

Is there a replacement library or method I can use instead of `HttpContextBase` in my `.NET Standard` library to share code?

Comment: As far as I know, you couldn't use httpcontextbase in asp.net core and there is no shared library could get it. I suggest you could try to use httpcontextbase in asp.net and use ihttpcontextaccessor in asp.net core to get useful information and then pass to the shared library to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/inc/usage_guidance) looks like it provides a few ways to convert between `System.Web.HttpContext` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext`, and the surrounding docs have some additional guidance for migrating from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core